# mat-autocomplete not binding correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

I'm attempting to use two matInput fields that each bind with separate mat-autocomplete panels. Following the steps [here](https://v6.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview), I'm able to get one to work fine, but I'm having difficulties with two input fields and autocomplete panels.

Here's my html:

```
<form>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="first" [formControl]="myControl">
     <mat-autocomplete #first="matAutocomplete">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions1 | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
     </mat-autocomplete>
   </mat-form-field>


   <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="second" [formControl]="otherControl">
     <mat-autocomplete #second="matAutocomplete">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions2 | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
       </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
   </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

Here's my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-property-create',
  templateUrl: './property-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./property-create.component.css']
})

export class PropertyCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  myControl = new FormControl();
  otherControl = new FormControl();

  options1: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  options2: string[] = ['Four', 'Five', 'Six'];

  filteredOptions1: Observable<string[]>;
  filteredOptions2: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.filteredOptions1 = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );

    this.filteredOptions2 = this.otherControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter2(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options1.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }

  private _filter2(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options2.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }

}
```

When linking each text input field to the corresponding panel, I'm using [matAutocomplete]="first" to link the first panel to the first text input. Based on the Angular Material docs, I was expecting to be able to link the second text input field to the second autocomplete panel by using [matAutocomplete]="second".

Right now my autocomplete panels are showing up in the same spot, rather than under the corresponding text field.

Has anyone seen this or know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Stackblitz would be the best

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you are missing the css classes for the form and mat-form-field elements:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input  placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="first">
    <mat-autocomplete #first="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions1|async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="otherControl" [matAutocomplete]="second">
    <mat-autocomplete #second="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions2| async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqax9d

Comment: Works in stackblitz but not on my machine. Would the css make a difference on the linking of text fields to autocomplete panels?

Another weird thing happening is the placeholder isn't minimizing when I click inside of the text field.

Comment: Make sure material and @angular/cdk versions match and have you included material css in project?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried running ng add `@angular/material` and reached the error: **Your project is not using the default configuration for build and test. The Angular Material schematics can only be used with the default configuration**

After changing my angular.json it's working now.

Comment: Cool! You figured it out.